# Angular 6 / NGRX Combine Reducers

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I am using Angular 6 w/ NgRX 4. I have multiple reducers I would like to combine.

**app.module.ts**

```
  import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
    import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';

    import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import counterEffects from './store/counter/counter.effects';

    import reducers from './store/reducers';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
        EffectsModule.forRoot([counterEffects]),
        StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
          maxAge: 10,
        }),
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

**reducers.ts**

```
import { combineReducers } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducer as counterReducer, key as counterKey } from './counter';
import { reducer as profileReducer, key as profileKey } from './profile';

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  [counterKey]: counterReducer,
  [profileKey]: profileReducer,
});

export default (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'REDIRECT_TO_EXTERNAL') {
    state = undefined;
  }

  return appReducer(state, action);
};
```

My reducers are standard reducers, nothing special there.

Coming from a React / Redux background, I would set multiple reducers up like this, however in Angular when I attempt to select from the store I get undefined. When I attempt to view the store using the dev tools, I can see none of my reducers and state is simply `{}`

How do I setup multiple reducers in Angular 6 / NgRX 4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducer as counterReducer, key as counterKey } from './counter';
import { reducer as profileReducer, key as profileKey } from './profile';

export interface IAppState {
  [counterKey]: any;
  [profileKey]: any;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<IAppState> = {
  [counterKey]: counterReducer,
  [profileKey]: profileReducer,
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to nest the ActionReducerMap? Lets say I want reducers to be part of other bigger reducer, how can it be done?

Comment: Is it possible to do what @UdiMazor asked?

Answer (score 0):

for me this blog helped:
https://blog.strongbrew.io/combinereducers-enhanced/

try this out:

```
export interface IAppState {
  [counterKey]: NestedType;
  [profileKey]: any;
}

export interface NestedType {
      [nestedKey1]: any;
      [nestedKey2]: any;
    }

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<IAppState> = {
  [counterKey]: combineReducers({
      [nestedKey1]: nestedKey1Reducer;
      [nestedKey2]: nestedKey2Reducer;
  }),
  [profileKey]: profileReducer,
};
```