# @ngrx/store Error on production build : Error during template compile of 'Store'

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

The error:

```
ERROR in ../@ngrx/store/store.ts(10,2): Error during template compile of 'Store'
Could not resolve @angular/core relative to /home/teebo/Development/node_modules/@ngrx/store/store.d.ts..
```

I am on Angular v6, and @ngrx/store 6.1.0.

I am exporting some reducers form ***./reducers/ui/index.ts*** like

```
export const uiReducers = combineReducers({
  formFields: fromFormFieldsReducer.reducer,
  forms: fromFormReducers.reducer,
  formGroups: fromFormGroupReducer.reducer
});
```

And then in ***appState.reducers.ts*** I have exports as follows

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import { uiReducers } from './reducers/ui';
import { UIState } from './models/ui.model';
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export interface AppState {
  ui: UIState;
}

export const reducerToken = new 
 InjectionToken<ActionReducerMap<AppState>>('Reducers');

 export function getReducers() {
   return { ui: uiReducers };
 }

 export const reducerProvider = [
   { provide: reducerToken, useFactory: getReducers }
 ];
```

And then in my ***app.module.ts*** I have the following

```
...
import { StoreModule, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { reducerToken, reducerProvider } from 
 './state_store/appState.reducers'; 
...
imports: [..., StoreModule.forRoot(reducerToken),...]
...
providers: [..., reducerProvider, ...]
```

But running the following npm script

```
"build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run 
 webpack:server",
```

I get the error

```
ERROR in ../@ngrx/store/store.ts(10,2): Error during template compile of 'Store'
Could not resolve @angular/core relative to /home/teebo/Development/node_modules/@ngrx/store/store.d.ts..
```

Any assistance with this issue would be much appreciated, thanks.
 I have followed do me threads on github to track the issue like this [one](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/306)

As doing it with a `ActionReducerMap` without the provider gives me

```
ERROR in app/app.module.ts(64,25): Error during template compile of 
'AppModule'
 Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'combineReducers' 
 was called in 'appStateReducers'
 'appStateReducers' references 'uiReducers' at 
 app/state_store/appState.reducers.ts(9,67)
  'uiReducers' calls 'combineReducers' at 
app/state_store/reducers/ui/index.ts(8,27).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to the issue by specifying in the `tsconfig.app.json` the path to the node_modules, the build with the `--prod` now works. The change I have made is as follows in the compiler options

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": { "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"] },
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not manually call the combineReducers function. As mentioned [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1179#issuecomment-404608996), you can try and use actionReducerMap for your reducers and pass it to `StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)`

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50804590/6663016) for implementation

Comment: bu I need to combine the reducers, I could I do that without calling the function?

Comment: yes , store will internally handle that, as mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @Teebo I have updated the link with sample implementation.